# CORS blocking Nexus javascript from running on Chrome, not Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cors, nexus

### Background Information

I'm trying to get a Nexus server up and running on my companies intranet for development purposes. I have it installed on Windows Server 2012 as a Service.

We have 2 supported browsers: Internet Explorer 11 and Google Chrome. Chrome seems to have been configured by our IT team as there's no Incognito Mode, so it's probable they have configured other things behind the scenes as well.

### The Error

Accessing the web interface from IE and Firefox both work fine, I can navigate through it with no errors. On Chrome however, I can't use any of the functionality as there is a SecurityError that gets thrown. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/07Jt1) is a picture of the error, and below is a transcription of the error message. (With the host and port changed to `foo` & `0001`)

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://foo:0001" from accessing a cross-origin frame. (http://foo:0001/static/rapture/nexus-coreui-plugin-prod.js?_v=3.6.0-02:1)
```

### Troubleshooting Steps

My first thought since it works on the other two browsers is that it's a chrome configuration issue. This would be a harder problem to solve though as our IT team is the one who did the configuration (likely for security purposes), and I assume they'd be reluctant to open up a vulnerability on purpose.

Also, the CORS error kind of confuses me since the request to the javascript file is happening on the originating server, same domain, port, and everything. I was under the impression that CORS issues happen when the requests are across different domains/ports/etc?

Are there any other ways I can get Nexus web interface to run on Chrome without triggering these security errors? Nobody wants to use Internet Explorer here, and Firefox isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out the issue is because I didn't follow my personal first rule of programming.

## Never Assume

(I assumed this particular extension wouldn't be causing any network errors)

Turns out I had an extension enabled (cVim) that was causing the CORS errors for whatever reason. I opened an issue [here.](https://github.com/1995eaton/chromium-vim/issues/584) to investigate why it may be happening. I'll update with results later.